# Emulating navigating between pages in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, navigation

There is a Page class and navigating functionality embedded in the WPF platform. I am developing a Window forms application and need a similar functionality. What is the easy and smooth way to emulate navigation between different forms? Or maybe there should be one form and some containers inside? How can I achieve the navigating functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Create a panel and `Dock` it to `Fill`.

Then `BringToFront`the panel.

Do this for every "Form" you need.

EDIT: This works as expected:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Shown += Form1_Shown;
    panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}

void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BringToFront();
    Update();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    panel2.BringToFront();
    Update();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    panel1.BringToFront();
}
```

EDIT: Added the `Update();`'s due to a comment.

Comment: Thanks. But BringToFront did not work. I have used Visible property of the panels.

Comment: @Peter17 `Visible` is fine. But I'm surprised `BringToFront` didn't work. I added code that works to my answer.

Comment: Calling Sleep(3000) on the UI thread is *exactly* enough to induce Windows to display the ghost window with the "Not Responding" message in the title bar.  Preventing you from actually seeing the panel2 ever being brought to the front.  This is a horribly bad example.

Comment: @HansPassant  "This works as expected" = I tried it and saw the panels change.